# Mock non-virtual methods using pre-processor

Tags: c++, mocking, embedded, googletest

I am working on an embedded project in C++ where the resources are a bit limited. This means I try to be careful about using too many virtual methods unless I really need them. I am planning to start implementing unit-tests perhaps with Gtest.

Because the project is not too big in code size most of the code is written directly in the header file. The only penalty is a bit more compiling time. As it takes ~20 seconds to compile this is not an issue and in my opinion makes code easier to write/read.

If the project was running in Windows I would be all for creating new abstraction layers (or adding seam classes) and having more virtual methods where I need them for unit-testing. Because of the nature of the project I don't want to add extra virtual methods just for unit-testing purposes. I think it would be valid to do it but seems a bit unreasonable when the resources are scarce.

The project is running well and unit-testing is nice to have so I would like to keep code modifications to a minimum. One of the solutions to the problem is to do some trickery with the templates using "hi-perf dependency injection". This to me seems like duck typing and still requires modifying the original source code where the class is used.

I was thinking why not just use the pre-processor:

```
#ifdef TEST
#define TESTABLE virtual
#else
#define TESTABLE
#endif
```

Then when the time comes that a method needs to be mocked you could always modify the original source code for that class and write something like:

```
TESTABLE void somePreviouslyUnmockeableMethod(void);
```

I am aware one of the disadvantages is that I would have now two source codes, one for production and one for testing. The same happens anyway when one decides to use a Mock class instead of the real class when unit-testing. If the code changes were quite big the changes with the pre-processor could be a real problem but I think with this definition they are kept to a minimum.

Is this a valid solution? Are the some negative consequences I may be overlooking?

Note that all the modules already include a `ProjectSettings.h` file where the `TESTABLE` definition could be added with ease.

Comment: Where's your evidence that use of virtual functions has an undue impact on resource usage?  Given that changing a function from `virtual` to non-`virtual` can change the behaviour of instances of *derived* classes (e.g. when they are accessed polymorphically by a pointer or reference to the base class) how will you establish that your testing is consistent with that the program does "in the wild"?

Comment: There is some overhead. It is not possible to say generally whether it will matter or not, it depends of the system it is run to if it is negligible or not. "Technical Report on C++ Performance" can be cited for more information. If you look [here](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/compilers/mikroc/pic/help/pic_specifics.htm)

Comment: If you look [here](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/compilers/mikroc/pic/help/pic_specifics.htm) you can see some devices may have a relative low "Nested Calls Limitations". So it does matter, in some cases the effect is negligible and in others it is not. If tomorrow the SW runs in an old PIC it may matter a lot. As for the virtual derived problem you mention that is a good point.

Comment: You should probably start with reviewing the overall OO design. Look for cases where you can remove inheritance. For example if you have some abstract driver class "UART port" which will only ever get inherited by the specific MCU driver, consider making a plain list of functions in a header and have the driver implement those, without involving any objects at all. Inheritance overall tends to create more problems than it solves, so it should only be used in cases where you absolutely without doubt need it.

Answer (score 0):

If making the classes virtual is really too costly (i.e. you measured that this would be too much overhead), you can use [hi-perf dependency injection](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/refs/tags/release-1.8.0/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-nonvirtual-methods) technique. The cost is then only i longer compilation time but no runtime overhead. In production you instantiate your class with real object and in tests - with a mock class that have methods with the same signatures as the real clas.

Comment: Maybe I should just start writing the unit-tests. In my mind there will be "many" cases where I will need to mock a non-virtual method and this approach will be too cumbersome. However looking at the code now slowly it doesn't seem that will be the case. Most modules are relatively independent with very few dependencies, there's only a few were there a way too many. If those are just a few the template way may be ok used there.